# using ng-repeat inside a vanilla HTML form

Tags: angularjs, html, forms, http-post

I ran into a problem when using ng-repeat inside a vanilla HTML form. I want to submit any fields that have been checked. However, despite everything around it being submitted, anything that is generated by ng-repeat is never submitted with the form.

```
<form name="someForm" action="someUrl" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="getsSubmmited1" value="true">
    <table>
        <TR ng-repeat="value in List">
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="{{value.key}}" value="{{value.key2}}"></TD>
        <TR>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="getsSubmmited2" value="true">
    <button to submit form>
</form>
```

My code looks something like the one above, I am lost as to why I am not able to get the ng-repeat fields on the other end. Thanks!

Comment: What is generated HTML?

Comment: So your code ISN'T the one above? If you posted your real html, in addition to the javascript, we'd be better able to help you.